# How to add a String Value/ Name Data pair in Windows Registry Editor key using C++ and Windows Registry API's

Tags: c++, windows, registry, regedit

I want to add a string name and its value to the Windows Registry using C++ code, to stop browsers other than Firefox stop running. I plan to do the Windows Registry editing in a loop for all browsers, but for now I am implementing it for Chrome only.

My current code below is adding a value to the `Default` string, and it is not working, but I want to create a `Debugger` string and set it to `"ntsd -c q"` in the `chrome.exe` subkey, as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Here is my code, which is adding `"ntsd -c q"` for the `Default` string and not creating a new `Debugger` string. I am not able to clearly understand from Microsoft's documentation about how to achieve this using C/C++. I have seen some solutions that do it via the command line, but co-workers are very ethical and they don't prefer that way.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    HKEY hkey;
    LSTATUS ReturnValue = 0;
    LPCTSTR Directory = TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\ NT\\CurrentVersion\\Image\ File\ Execution\ Options\\chrome.exe");
    ReturnValue = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, Directory, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hkey);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != ReturnValue)
    {
        printf("RegOpenKeyEx failed\n");
        printf("%d\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }
    //LPCSTR value = "Debugger";
    //ReturnValue = RegQueryValueEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, Directory, NULL, NULL, value, sizeof(value));
    
    LPCSTR Value = "ntsd\ -c\ q\0";
    ReturnValue = RegSetValueA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\ NT\\CurrentVersion\\Image\ File\ Execution\ Options\\chrome.exe",REG_SZ, Value, sizeof(Value));
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != ReturnValue)
    {
        printf("RegStatusValueA failed\n");
        printf("%d\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }
    
    ReturnValue = RegCloseKey(hkey);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != ReturnValue)
    {
        printf("RegCloseKey failed\n");
        printf("%d\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you say what doesn't happen, but you never said what *does* happen. What do the function calls return?

Comment: You might need to be running elevated to write to that key.  If you answer Raymonds' question, that should tell us.  Also, do you really _need_ `KEY_ALL_ACCESS`?

Comment: none of the functions return any error and run successfully, they never go inside the if statements and I am a rookie so I don't know about ```KEY_ALL_ACEES``` but basically I want to write in a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KEY_ALL_ACCESS` requires admin rights. All you really need in this situation is `KEY_SET_VALUE` instead.  Don't ask for more permissions than you actually need.  But, you do still need admin rights to write to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` to begin with.  So make sure you are running your code as an elevated user.

In any case, your string literals have a few `\` that don't belong. But more importantly, your use of `RegSetValueA()` is completely wrong for this task.  It is a deprecated API that can only write to the `(Default)` string and nothing else (and, you are not even calling it correctly anyway, you would need `strlen(Value)+1` instead of `sizeof(Value)` - not that it matters because that parameter is ignored anyway).

In order to create your `Debugger` string value, you need to use `RegSetValueEx()` instead, eg:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    HKEY hkey;
    LPCTSTR Directory = TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Image File Execution Options\\chrome.exe");
    LSTATUS ReturnValue = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, Directory, 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, &hkey);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != ReturnValue)
    {
        printf("RegOpenKeyEx failed: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }
    LPCTSTR Value = TEXT("ntsd -c q");
    ReturnValue = RegSetValueEx(hkey, TEXT("Debugger"), 0, REG_SZ, (const BYTE*)Value, (lstrlen(Value)+1) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != ReturnValue)
    {
        printf("RegSetValueExA failed: %u\n", GetLastError());
        RegCloseKey(hkey);
        return -1;
    }
    
    ReturnValue = RegCloseKey(hkey);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != ReturnValue)
    {
        printf("RegCloseKey failed: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Remy. This code worked.